# ¿Cómo poner el ancho de las columnas de un Excel dependiendo del contenido de la columna?

Tags: simplexlsx

quería preguntar si había una forma de que el ancho de cada columna de Excel se pueda poner dependiendo del contenido, para poder ponerlo antes de descargar el Excel.

Este es el código que tengo.

```
 exportarExcel() {
    const workSheetData: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(this.dataToJson(this.datos));
    const workSheetQuery: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(this.dataHeaderToJson());
    const workBook: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workBook, workSheetQuery, this.translate.instant('general.consulta'));
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workBook, workSheetData, this.translate.instant('general.datos'));
    


    XLSX.writeFile(workBook, `Operadores.xlsx`);
  }
```

Me ayudaría un montón si alguien me puede ayudar porque  no tengo mucha experiencia con la librería de Excel xlsx.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo usando el objeto `cols` de la hoja de trabajo (worksheet) de XLSX.

```
exportarExcel() {
    const workSheetData: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(this.dataToJson(this.datos));
    const workSheetQuery: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(this.dataHeaderToJson());
    const workBook: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workBook, workSheetQuery, this.translate.instant('general.consulta'));
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workBook, workSheetData, this.translate.instant('general.datos'));

    // Ajusta el ancho de las columnas basado en el contenido
    workSheetData['!cols'] = Object.keys(this.datos[0]).map(key => ({wch: Math.max(...this.datos.map(obj => obj[key].toString().length))}));
    workSheetQuery['!cols'] = Object.keys(this.dataHeaderToJson()[0]).map(key => ({wch: Math.max(...this.dataHeaderToJson().map(obj => obj[key].toString().length))}));

    XLSX.writeFile(workBook, `Operadores.xlsx`);
}
```

Ten en cuenta que la función `Math.max(...this.datos.map(obj => obj[key].toString().length))` es una forma simplista de obtener el ancho de la columna

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias.